# When should I use return?

Tags: javascript

It's a petty basic question which seems I don't fully understand,

What exactly is the use of `return`? In what cases should I use it?

What would the difference between these code samples be?

```
function fun(text) {
  console.log(text);
};

function fun(text) {
  return console.log(text);
};
```

To be clear: I know what `return` *does*, I just don't feel like I fully understand it's purpose and when should I use it

Comment: use it when someone wants/need the output value of a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `return` if your function needs to, well, return anything to its caller. In your example, it's not necessary to use return because `console.log` already does what you want it to do. But, if your function calculates something (for example a mathematical operation like adding the first two params it receives), it's logical it "returns" the result, like this:

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

This way the function caller can use the result for whatever it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

`return` is used to send a value back to where's it's called from.  You use it if you want to return a value.

If you don't have a return statement, it's the same as `return undefined`.  `console.log` returns `undefined`, so `return console.log(text)` returns `undefined`.

So, only `return` if you want to get a value from the function.

Answer (score 1):

`return` exits from the function, possibly with a value.

Lets say we have these two functions:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function bar(a) {
    if (a > 10)
        return;
    // Do something with 'a'
}
```

If the first function, `foo`, `return` exits the function and the result of calling the function (e.g. `var c = foo(1, 2)`) is the result of the expression given to `return`, in this case the sum of `a` and `b`.

In the second function, `bar`, `return` is used to exit the function if `a` is larger than 10, but otherwise execution of the function continues. It doesn't return with a value like `foo`, so using `bar` as part of an expression could result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

return halts the execution of the function and defines the value that is returned as the result of calling the function.